# Proportionality of constant in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: geometry, analysis, inequality

It is said in the proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in one book that the function $f(t):=|x+ty|^2=|x|^2+2t\langle x,y \rangle + t^2|y|^2$ (for $t\in\mathbb{R}$) equals zero only if $|\langle x,y \rangle |=|x||y|$, and thus $|\langle x,y \rangle |=|x||y|$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are proportional.

Then the proof to a corollary to this theorem, which is the triangle inequality, shows that equality of the triangle inequality holds if and only if $x$ and $y$ are proportional with a nonnegative proportionality factor.

However, it appears to be the case that for $f(t)$ to equal $0$, we need $t$ be a negative number. Otherwise, how can $f(t)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably misreading something. It's not $f(t)$ who is assumed to be $0$, but the discriminant of the equation $|x|^2 + 2t \langle x, y \rangle + t^2 |x|^2 = 0$. This discriminant is $4 (\langle x, y \rangle ^2 - |x|^2 |y|^2)$. From its equality with $0$ (and not from $f(t) = 0$, mind you!) you get $|\langle x, y \rangle | = |x| |y|$ etc.

The equality $f(t) = 0$ indeed cannot hold for $t>0$, as you say, but this has nothing to do with the equality case in the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality that you are studying. You are making a correct remark about something that does not matter.

---

Let's see what the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says, and what it doesn't say. Take two arbitrary vectors $x$ and $y$ and consider the function $f : \Bbb R \to [0, \infty)$ given by $f(t) = |x + ty|^2$. Clearly $f(t) = |x|^2 + 2t \langle x, y \rangle + t^2 |y|^2$.

Let $\Delta = 4 (\langle x, y \rangle ^2 - |x|^2 |y|^2)$ be the discriminant of the equation $|x|^2 + 2t \langle x, y \rangle + t^2 |y|^2 = 0$. Since $f(t) \ge 0$, there are two possibilities: either $f(t) > 0$, so the equation has no real root, so $\Delta < 0$; or there is exactly one $t$ with $f(t) = 0$ (if there were two of them, $f$ would be negative between them, which is impossible), and in this case $\Delta = 0$. We conclude that $\Delta \le 0$, i.e. $| \langle x, y \rangle | \le |x| |y|$.

When do we have equality above, i.e. when do we have $| \langle x, y \rangle | = |x| |y|$? Let us prove that we have equality if and only if $x = cy$ for some $c \in \Bbb R$.

If $x = cy$, then $| \langle x, y \rangle | = | \langle x, cx \rangle | = |c| | \langle x, x \rangle | = |c| |x|^2 = |x| |cx| = |x| |y|$, so indeed in this case we have equality. Notice that in this situation $f(t) = |x|^2 |1 + ct|^2$, which shows that if $x = cy$ then $f(t) \ne 0$ in general, unless $t = - \frac 1 c$ (or unless $x = y = 0$, but this is trivial). Since $c$ may be negative, it follows that $- \frac 1 c$ may be positive. A concrete example: for $x = -y$, the (unique) root of $f$ will be $t=1$.

Conversely, if $| \langle x, y \rangle | = |x| |y|$ (and assuming $x \ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$), we get that $|\cos (\widehat {x,y})| = 1$, so $\widehat {x, y}$ is either $0$ or $\pi$, meaning that there exists $c \in \Bbb R$ such that $x = cy$.

Comment: But don't we consider a discriminant only when we try to find roots of a quadratic equation, that is when we equate $f(t)$ to $0$?

Comment: @sequence: Not only then. In this case we consider the discriminant because we want our equation *not* to have *distinct* roots, because then it would have to take negative values (between the roots), which wouldn't be possible given that $f(t)$ is the square of a real number.

Comment: So $f(t)$ has one root when the discriminant is $0$. However, this still means $f(t)=0$, correct?

Comment: @sequence: Correct. Notice that the corresponding $t$ wouldn't have to be $<0$, though, because even with $t>0$ the scalar product $\langle x, y \rangle$ could be "negative enough" to compensate for all the "positiveness" in that expression.

Comment: However, if $\langle x,y \rangle = |x||y|$ (the case when equality holds) then $t$ cannot be positive? How can the equality in the triangle inequality then hold (since the proportionality constant must be positive there)?  @AlexM.

Comment: @sequence: You confuse the equality $f(t) = 0$ (which is not interesting) with the case of equality  $| \langle x, y \rangle | = |x| |y|$ in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The two are unrelated, none of them implying the other. I simply don't understand what you don't understand: you seem to turn in circles around one and the same false problem. In order to help you, you must help me understand where your confusion lies.

Comment: (1) Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: Equality holds iff $x$ and $y$ are proportional. $\implies$ (2) $f(t)=0$. (3) Triangle inequality: equality holds iff $x$ and $y$ are proportional. $\implies$ (4) $\langle x, y\rangle = c\langle y, y\rangle \implies |x||y| = |c||y||y| = |c||y|^2 \implies c>0 \implies t>0$ in $f(t) \implies f(t) = 0$, which is impossible, because $f(t)=|x|^2+2t\langle x,y\rangle +t^2|y|^2=|x|^2 + 2|t||x||y|+t^2|y|^2\ne 0$!  @AlexM.

Comment: @sequence: I have expanded my answer in the hope that it will help you clarify the confusion.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that actually, but the thing is that my book claims that $c$ must necessarily be a positive proportionality constant in the case when equality holds in the triangle inequality, and the book does prove that. But in the C-S inequality case, it appears that the proportionality constant is not necessarily positive, while it must be positive in C-S if it is positive in T-E. @AlexM.

Comment: @sequence: I agree with the last comment: equality in the TI implies a positive proportionality constant. But why does that bother you? Why do you believe that the equality case in the CSI should be related to the equality case in the TI? They are not, they live in different worlds. The CSI tells you something about angles (between edges), while the TI tells you something about lengths (of edges).

Comment: We have to use the CSI in order to prove the TI. When we prove equality in the TI, we discover that $x$ and $y$ are proportional, but this implies that equality also holds in the CSI. That is, I think that equality holds in CSI if and only if it holds in TI. Please correct me if I'm wrong. And if I'm not wrong then proportionality in TI implies proportionality in CSI. If this is correct then proportionality constant $c>0$ in TI implies $c>0$ in CSI, which is impossible. @AlexM.

Comment: @sequence: You're wrong. :) Equality in the TI (i.e. positive proportionality constant) does imply equality in the CSI, but the converse is **not** true (this seems to be your mistake and the source of your struggle): taking $y = -x$ satisfies the equality in the CSI, but gives you $0 \le |x| + |x|$ in the TI.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks for clarifying.